# How to prove: If $a \to -\infty $ and $b$ is bounded from below by a constant $k\in\Bbb R^{>0}$, then the $a\cdot b\to -\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

I must proof the following, with $a: \Bbb{N} \to \Bbb{R}$ and $b: \Bbb{N} \to \Bbb{R}$

If $a \to -\infty\ (n\to\infty)$ and $b$ is bounded from below by a constant $k\in\mathbb R^{>0}$, then the  $a\cdot b \to -\infty\ (n\to\infty)$

I thinked: If $a \to -\infty\ (n\to\infty)$ then $\forall\ M\in\mathbb R( \exists t\in \Bbb{N}( \forall n \ge t( a_n < -M)))$, therefore also $a_n < -M/k$ and $a_n \cdot k <-M$... but I do not know continue, How can I do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: All you have to add is that for $n$ large enough, $a_n<0$ and hence $a_n b_n\leq a_n k$ because $b_n\geq k$.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker, or Can I study $a_n<-\frac{|M|}{k}$ ??

Comment: Ultimately, you want to show that for each $N$, $a_n b_n<-N$ for $n$ large enough. Keep the goal in mind.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker, I understand.. thanks soo much! :)

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered in comments:

> All you have to add is that for $n$ large enough, $a_n<0$ and hence $a_nb_n\leq a_nk$ because $b_n\geq k$.
>
> Ultimately, you want to show that for each $N$, $a_nb_n<−N$ for $n$ large enough. Keep the goal in mind. –  Michael Greinecker♦ Jan 28 at 0:15